# Deploying node js using octopus

Tags: macos, deployment, bamboo, octopus

I am completely new to octopus. Basically i want to deploy a node application to an EC2 instance. I am using bitbucket for my sources and bamboo for CI. I wanted to know how exactly to proceed further. Or if i want to deploy my node application using octopus, should i package my node application in specific way? Or is there any tool which is actually feasible than octopus. As octopus is known for .net platform deployment. I am using mac. Do we have octopus server installer for mac?So that i can play around with it locally. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need to use octopus? You can upload your node to S3 and then use Bamboo CodeDeploy task to start it at AWS instances: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/using-the-aws-codedeploy-task-750396059.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Octopus needs a Windows machine to run the Server component. You can deploy to a target [over SSH](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/SSH+Targets) - so your EC2 machine doesn't need to be running Windows.

There's a [guide to deploying a node.js app with Octopus](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=3049551) that's probably the best place to start.

The deployment process should be fairly straightforward. Most likely a [Package Step](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Deploying+packages) followed by a bash script to spin up or restart your node application.

To create a package to send to Octopus, [create a zip or tarball](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Supported+Packages) containing all of the files you need for your node application to run. You can use octopackjs for this. It should be appropriately named with the version number as per that documentation page.

Adding a [step at the end of your Bamboo build to tell Octopus to create a Release](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Bamboo#Bamboo-Creatingarelease) is relatively straightforward, as is [deploying releases](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Bamboo#Bamboo-DeployingreleaseswithOctopusandBamboodeploymentplans).